# How do i use/print the value inside a generic attribute in TestCafe

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, e2e-testing, testcafe

What I'm trying to do is print/use the value of the [Polyline](https://www.w3schools.com/graphics/svg_polyline.asp) attribute.

```
<Polyline points="x,y x,y x,y x,y">
```

I've tried to get them with these methods:

This is an util function

```
export const getPointAttribute = async () => {
  const polyline = s.polyline;
  const polylineData = ClientFunction(() => polyline().attributes, {
    dependencies: { polyline }
  });
  return polylineData 
}
```

This is inside the test script

```
test('', async (t) => {
   console.log(u.getPointAttribute())
}
```

or

```
test('', async (t) => {
   console.log(s.polyline.getAttribute('points'));
}
```

And I include my selectors external

```
import * as s from '../utilities/selectors';
```

But all I get is a promise as output in the console log

> Promise {  }

or

> ReExecutablePromise { _then: [], _fn: [Function], _taskPromise: null }

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should await the call inside the console.log:

```
test('', async (t) => {
   console.log(await s.polyline.getAttribute('points'));
}
```

or

```
test('', async (t) => {
   console.log(await s.polyline.getAttribute('points'));
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Your `getPointAttribute` function returns the `polylineData` object that is an instance if the [ClientFunction type](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/reference/test-api/clientfunction/) (which is, in turn, based on Promises). That's why when you log `u.getPointAttribute()`, you get these messages. All you need to do is to use the `await` keyword before calling the ClientFunction. Please see the following code:

```
const polylineData = ClientFunction(() => polyline().attributes, {
    dependencies: { polyline }
});
await polylineData();
```

Refer to the following article to get more information https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/obtaining-data-from-the-client/

I would also like to mention that you do not need to use `async`in your `getPointAttribute` function.

Comment: Thanks for your response! The async was a sloppy copy, thanks for noticing, it is removed. Unfortunately the function still returns:
 Promise { <pending> }

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to get it working with a utility function for the ones who are interested.

```
export function getPoints(object: Selector) : Promise<string> {
  return object.getAttribute('points');
}
```

This makes it easier and cleaner to work with the data.

```
import * as u from '../utilities/functions';
import * as s from '../utilities/selectors';
console.log(await u.getPoints( s.polyline ));
```

Thanks for the help guys!